# appveyor running after build action only on master branch

Tags: appveyor

I have repo building in *AppVeyor* which produces some packages (`.nupkg`) that are then pushed to *MyGet*. When I am developing on master everything is peachy, but when I'm on another branch I want it to build but NOT push packages, I have read [some documentation](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/branches/) on branches and it seems I can have one configuration for master and another for the other branches, however that would mean to duplicate all my configuration except for the line that actually pushes to *MyGet*. My `appveyor.yml` file looks something like this:

```
version: 0.0.{version}

before_build:
  - do some stuff (I have about 5 of these)
  - ...

build_script:
  - cmd: build.cmd

after_build:
  - push to myGet
```

I would just like to run the `after_build` command if is on the `master` branch.

Is there a way to run some commands depending on their branch without rewriting the entire configuration for that branch (or branch type or whatever)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH` environment variable. Please try this:

```
after_build:
  - IF %APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH%==master push to myGet
```

Ilya.

Comment: I ended up using something like that inside a *PowerShell* script. I was hoping there was a more explicit way to do so using some *AppVeyor* specific config like `on branch: master` on something like that. Thanks for the answer though ;).

Comment: Note that this solution does not work for PR's. Because "APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH - build branch. For Pull Request commits it is base branch PR is merging into"

Comment: `APPVEYOR_PULL_REQUEST_HEAD_REPO_BRANCH` environment variable is available.

Comment: Note, that builds started by a tag will leave `APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH` undefined